# Como recuperar valores de checkbox desmarcados com PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

Preciso identificar campos em checkbox que estão desmarcados via PHP

Comment: Se não veio no POST/GET é pq esta desmarcado. Se quer mais detalhes, é importante acrescentar um trecho do código HTML com os checkboxes na pergunta para facilitar pra quem responde, e explicar como eles são gerados (se é manual, se é outro PHP que gera, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simples, monte um ternário:

```
$checboxName = isset($_POST['name'])?true:false;
```

se ele existe então foi setado, se não não.

#### EDIT

Caso você tenha muitos `checkboxs` e não deseje verificas todos eles via ternário, você deve fazer um `event` no javascript para setar em `value` no `input` antes dele ser enviado.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<form method="post" id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(){ // CRIA EM EVENTO QUE É DISPARADO QUANDO O ELEMENTO DE ID 'form' FOR 'submetido/enviado'.
        var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName('input'); // PEGA TODOS OS INPUTS PRESENTES NESSE ELEMENTO
        for(var i in inputs){ // ITERA OS INPUTS
            var input = inputs[i];
            if(input.type == 'checkbox'){ // CASO SEJA UM 'checkbox'
                input.value = input.checked; // SETA 'value' COM TRUE/FALSE DE ACORDO COM O CHECKED
            }
            input.checked = true; // SETA COMO CHECKED PARA QUE ELE SEJA ENVIADO, O VALOR VALIDO É O QUE ESTA NO 'value' DO ELEMENTO
        }
    });
</script>
```

#### Problemas

- Este método gera um efeito visual ruim, pois ao enviar o formulário todos os `checked` ficam marcados, mesmo não sendo verdadeiros, para resolver isso você pode usar ajax.
- O PHP captura o valor do `$_POST` como string. Então mesmo enviado true/false, este sera string. Para resolver este problema pode se usar a esta função.

#### Verifica String true/false

```
function is_true($var){
    if(is_string($var)){
        if(preg_match('~^(false|f)$~', $var) != null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !!$var;
}
```

Comment: O caso é que tenho diversos checkbox, não queria reescrever em tudo, gostaria de saber se existe um modo de ele me indicar caso o input não estivesse marcado

Comment: @Tales atualizado, seja se agora esta ok.